# Eslint with Vue gives function is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, eslint

Is there a way to fix this error in vue js ( vue3 )
before this error I have errors about prettier
[image: no-unused-vars error]

when I run *"npm run serve"* I have this error
I use *"npm run lint -- --fix"* but nothing change

**LoginPage.vue**
[image: LoginPage-1]

[image: LoginPage-2]

**eslintrc.js**

[image: eslintrc.js]

Comment: Not an expert on Vue but aren't we suppose to expose methods as a part of export? As in, in `{ methods: {}, ...}`

Comment: Just add 'no-unused-vars': 'off' or 'no-unused-vars': 'warn' rule. You may need it any way, considering that it warns about right thing. These vars aren't used indeed, which could be  a mistake

Comment: Maybe you should add `setup` in `script` tag(<script setup>...</script>), because I guess you want to use [this](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) syntax.

Comment: @EstusFlask I don't understand your solution bro, can you explain please

Comment: @koishi doesn't work bro

Comment: You need to edit eslintrc.js and add this rule. But any way, you need to not just remove these errors but what they mean. In your code show and icon are really unused. In case you expected that show is used in a template, this is wrong because it's not exposed with <script> and no setup as mentioned above

Comment: You are using vue with vanilla. ‘Onclick’ is standard html event definition. Try changing onclick to ‘@click=show’. Besides that you have to rework the component to fully use vuejs and to avoid such errors in the future. Also, change the rule as mentioned above to “warn”

Answer (score 1):

It literally tells you what the problem is

Don't remove unused var checks in eslint, thats just lazy.

It sees two problems with your code:

1. You are using composition API, yet you have not included setup in your script tag. Your script opening tag should look like `<script setup>` this. Ref: [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles)
2. Your show function doesn’t use icon variable. So it should be removed since it creates unnecessary noise in the code.

Hope this helps